# I am 16 years old and accidentally requested a B1/B2 visa instead of a B2. Should that be a problem?

Tags: visas, usa, applications

I am 16 years old and accidentally requested a B1/B2 visa instead of a B2. Obviously as a 16 years old teenager I am not traveling to the US for business.

I am traveling to the US with my mom and she requested a B1/B2 visa as well, while she should have requested a B2.

Will they say something about that in the interview? Would that be a problem? My mom and I have already paid the fees.

Comment: It should not be a problem.  Most accepted B-2 applicants are given a B-1/B-2 visa anyway.  It is apparently common for consulates to issue a different type of visa than requested, perhaps based on information discussed at the interview.  Of course, if you never intend to visit for business during the validity of the visa, it will not matter which type of visa you get.

Comment: I applied for visas for my whole family. My wife and I were to get B1/B2, the rest (4 children) B2. In the end I just applied for B1/B2 for all six of us, and that's what they gave us, including our 3yo. It won't be a problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Being 16 years old does not preclude you from traveling to the USA on business, there are plenty of teenage entrepreneurs in this day & age.

Most people refer to a US visa as a "B1/B2" and the majority of visas issued are B1/B2.  So your "mistake" of requesting a B1/B2 instead of just a B2 will not be held against you.  The consular officials reviewing your application and interviewing you are more concerned with your financial well being and desire to return to your home country.  They may choose to amend your application data in their system to be just for a B2 or they may just ignore that aspect.

I would not lose any sleep worrying over it.